# I'm using Sphinx documentation tool which shows error: "maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp"

Tags: python, recursion, python-sphinx

I am using `Sphinx` documentation tool. While making `HTML` files using `RST` files, following error is shown with a hint to solve the error:

> Recursion error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in `cmp` This can happen with very large or deeply nested source files.
>
> You can carefully increase the default Python recursion limit of 1000 in
>   `conf.py` with Example:
>
> `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)`

I have tried increasing the `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, but this solution is not working out.

Apart from this, I tried changing the theme for HTML output. But the error remains; regardless of HTML theme.

Comment: do you have the full traceback? It is hard to help you without knowing where the error is coming from?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I am not getting full traceback.

The system says:  _build succeeded, 5 warnings._ 

After that above _Recursion error_ is shown.

I was looking into **Temp** folder for full traceback. Do I have to check some where else?

Comment: I'm sure that you are not going to solve the problem increasing the recursion limit. Usually if you hit this error, there is some bug. Look at the help of ``sphinx-build`` there are a few options (e.g. ``-P``, ``-W`` that might help)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, and tried slowly increasing the recursionLimit, which was a waste of time (is started having segmentation faults at ~40300).

What solved the problem for me was editing my index.rst

I had a wildcard in the toctree like this

```
MyCodeLibrary
##############

.. toctree::
   :glob:

   /*
```

I fixed it by doing this:

```
MyCodeLibrary
##############

.. toctree::
   :glob:

   mycodelibrary/*
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I attempted to do this, and it yields no results at all, is anyone else encountering this issue? I increased the recursion limit to something like 10000, and addressed the wildcard